# Winforms: What Determines if Docking Moves Other Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, panel

For example, within a TabPage, I have a DataGridView that is docked "Fill". If I set the dock property of a UserControl to the the "Right" position, the DataGridView moves to the left as expected. If I replace the UserControl with a Panel or Label (also docked to the "Right" within the TabPage) the DataGridView does not make room. The Panel or Label just overlay the DataGridView. I tried stackoverflow and did some reading but did not see any rules (yet). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their Z-order.  You can manipulate it with the Bring to Front and Move to Back context menu items, right-click a control to see the menu.

It is much clearer when you use the View + (Other Windows) + Document Outline window, it lists them in Z-order underneath their container.  And allows you to drag+drop the controls to change their order, you see the effect in the designer immediately.

Comment: For controls added at runtime, their z-order is index in `Controls` collection, right? From bottom (first added) to top (last added)?

Comment: Yes.  Index 0 is the top of the Z-order.  Controls.Add() appends at the end, puts the control at the bottom of the Z-order.  Controls.SetChildIndex() to change that.

Comment: This is exactly opposite to what I've guessed. Thanks.