# Parent form's control to be in front of child form (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, parent-child

I have a program with a horizontal dropbox with 4 options to choose from in which "sub buttons" will appear when I click on one of these buttons:

Here is the interface:

[image: Here is the interface]

And what I want to do is that when I click on one of the drop down menu options, I want a childform to spawn on the black area, using this:

```
private Form activeForm = null;

    private void openChildForm(Form childForm)
    {
        if (activeForm != null)
            activeForm.Close();
        activeForm = childForm;
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        MainInterfacePanel.Controls.Add(childForm);
        MainInterfacePanel.Tag = childForm;
        childForm.BringToFront();
        childForm.Show();
    }
```

However, when I do so, the childform does appear normally, but it covers the dropdown menu, preventing me to select other functions:

Here's how it looks like(the childform is still a blank form, thus the whiteness):

[image: Here's how it looks like(the childform is still a blank form, thus the whiteness)]

I tried solving this issue by using `item.bringToFront()` on the buttons, but it dosent seem to work.

Basically, I want the Parent Form to stay behind the childform, while having the buttons be infront of the childform, like an overlap. Is there a way to do so?

Also, when I remove the 'childForm.BringToFront()', for whatever reason it spawns behind the interface.

Comment: I think you can do this by making your application an MDI application. It will handle your window creation, size and position. You can find lots of information about it on google

Comment: @HansPassant Thats what I did, I've added a panel on the black area, and dock filled it in there, the only problem was that the spawned child form was in front of the dropdown menu. But you've gave me the idea to maybe send the panel to the back, maybe that does something.Edit: Nope, didnt seem to work:(

Comment: @GuidoG Ok, I'll try to look about about those. I just hope I won't have to do another overhaul of my program...xD

Comment: [Right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21858737/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant will look into that

Comment: You could also build real MenuItems and DropDownItems and *configure* them to be presented the way you want. You can customize MenuItems in all details. If you build a MenuStrip/MenuItem, first set their AutoSize property to false, then see [ToolStripProfessionalRenderer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer) and [ProfessionalColorTable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable). A base customization implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130479/7444103) (same thing in C#).

Comment: @GuidoG From what I found, it seems that I will need to make the entire form a container, therefore it wouldn't be compatible with how my program works. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @Jimi That might be an complete overhaul of my current program, so I'll leave that as last resort. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It may look like an overhaul modification, but note that you're now trying to implement something that is not supported by the .Net infrastructure (thus you'll have to handle all the possible exception and edge cases in addition to the default design challenge), while the Menu System is a standard feature with lots of well tested tools and predictable behaviors. Graphics elements are also supported out-of-the-box. It may take a few hours to get used to (it's all actually quite simple, if you look at the sample code I linked), but, after that, it's all well setup and quite easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use **Panel** in which child form may appear. Simply add **Panel** from **Toolbox** and change its **Dock** property to top and place all your menu items in that Panel and also add new **Panel** i.e. **MainPanel** to display forms and than use following code to display form inside the **Panel**

```
    SubForm objForm=new SubForm();
    objForm.TopLevel = false;
    MainPanel.Controls.Add(objForm);
    objForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
    objForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    objForm.Show();
```